# Custom referencing format in CSL document, Want to add whitespace into bibliography

Tags: xml, ms-word, csl

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/K34W6.png)

I want to make the bibliography style look like the bottom reference, the top reference is what I currently have using IEEE. I think I need to edit the .csl file but I'm not sure the best way to introduce the whitespace I want.

The start of the bibliography text should always be inline event when the citation number exceeds one digit, so I dont think hardcoding a number of spaces into the prefix will work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. In terms of software I am using Zotero and Word for mac.

I have tried adding CSS into the style section but that did not pass CSL validation.

Playing with the margin-left in the bibliography didn't change the text positioning either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From CSL's perspective you're looking for the solution in the wrong place: If you look at the screenshot below, CSL (via Zotero in this case) inserts a tab and a line feed in Word. The exact width of the line feed is not a question of the citation style but of typography/design (just like, say, font) so this is something you'd handle in your word processor. In your case, specifically, you can modify the `bibliography` style in Word (in this case by increasing the width of the hanging indentation).
[image: IEEE Bibliography in Word created by Zotero]